# Qt: Serial Library that supports Baud Rate 250k

Tags: qt, serial-port, qextserialport, qtserialport

I've given both `QSerialPort` and `QExtSerialPort` a try and neither seem to be able to support 250k correctly. `QExtSerialPort` does seem to have support for it as it's a listed baud type but whenever I use it to connect to a board all I get back is junk data like the baud rate is set incorrectly. I've verified all other settings, and the board does work over 250k as I've tested using miniterm to it. Are there any other libraries or should I be trying something different with `QExtSerialPort`?

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about Miniterm, not Minicom or something else? Miniterm is a helper application on OS/X, it's not really usable by itself. If you're talking about Minicom, then I can look at its source code and compare with `QSerialPort`'s.

Comment: Ah sorry I should have been more exact, it's miniterm.py.

Comment: Can you let me know exactly where you downloaded your miniterm.py and what version is it? There seems to be a multitude of copies out there.

Answer (score 0):

I presume your platform must be Linux, since on Windows there's really only one way of setting the baud rate, and if it doesn't work, then it won't work for everyone.

There is the issue of rounding. `QSerialPort` code simply divides the base baud generator clock by your baudrate. This is an integer division and is done with truncation. If whatever baudrate you select is not exactly supported by the hardware, the truncation may shift it in an invalid direction - there could have been a closer divisor that's larger, not smaller. You should check the baud generator base frequency and select your baud rate accordingly.

There are [many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19440269/1329652) of setting baud rates on Linux. `QSerialPort` does not support two methods out of the three in the cited answer. Thus it won't support some drivers that happen to support only the two out of the three methods. I don't know offhand how many drivers might suffer from that issue - it could be a red herring, after all.

Please share what is the exact driver is used for your device on Linux, and what is the kernel version. I can have a look and check if this driver would cause issues with current `QSerialPort` code.

To avoid rounding issues, as a temporary workaround you can extract the base baudrate generator frequency via the following hack:

```
// This must be at the very top of the .cpp file
#define private public
#include <QSerialPort>
#include "private/qserialport_p.h"
#include "private/qserialport_unix_p.h"
#undef private

QSerialPort * port;
...
// after the port was opened
int baudBase = port->d_ptr->currentSerialInfo.baud_base;
```

In the `.pro` file, you need `QT += core-private`, and this is for Qt 5. For Qt 4 you need to have Qt with available sources.

The real fix, of course, belongs in `QSerialPort`. I know nothing about `QExtSerialPort`.

Comment: I'll give this a go today. It works fine if the board is at baud rate 115k but the 200k just seems to be a no go, so there's a backup option at least.

Comment: Just one thing I forgot to mention, it's a crossplatform application which is why I was trying to use Qt's QSerialPort to abstract it out a bit. Currently building it on OS X.

Comment: On OS X, the `QSerialPort` code also uses only one of two ways of setting a custom baud rate, it skips, in fact, the simpler way of doing it that may be supported by more drivers. It uses a `IOSSIOSPEED` ioctl, instead of using `c_ispeed` and `c_ospeed` in the `termios` structure (accessible via `cfsetpspeed(...)`).

Comment: yeah it works fine using Miniterm and connecting over 250k. It's an FTDI I think, the hardware is not my area of experience.

Comment: @ Kuba Ober: can you provide how to achieve it with Qt5.5 as the qserialport_unix_p.h is not available under Mac.

Comment: @steffenmauch Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Well, my application runs fine at Windows with an FT232R. Right now, I tried it with Mac and there it only works with 115200 instead of the 2000000. It is using QT5.5 on Mac OS X 10.11.