# How to set a non-standard baudrate on a serial port device on Linux?

Tags: linux, serial-port, tty

What are the ways of setting custom baudrates on Linux?

An answer to this question must be at a level of userland low-level APIs (`ioctl`, etc.) above the level of a syscall. It should be useful in these circumstances at least:

1. Writing low-level C-based userland code that uses serial ports,
2. Writing libraries that abstract the serial port functionality,
3. Writing kernel serial port drivers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Things are, unfortunately, driver-dependent. Good drivers will implement all of the methods below. Bad drivers will implement only some of the methods. Thus you need to try them all. All of the methods below are implemented in the helper functions in [linux/drivers/tty/serial/serial_core.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/tty/serial/serial_core.c).

The following 4 choices are available.

1. Standard baud rates are set in `tty->termios->c_cflag`. You can choose from:

   ```
       B0
       B50
       B75
       B110
       B134
       B150
       B200
       B300
       B600
       B1200
       B1800
       B2400
       B4800
       B9600
       B19200
       B38400
       B57600
       B115200
       B230400
   ```
2. If you need rates not listed above, e.g. 460800 (this is a deprecated hack that the kernel developers wish to die, per the source code comments):

   - set `tty->termios->c_cflag` speed to `B38400`
   - call `TIOCSSERIAL` ioctl with (struct serial_struct) set as follows:

     ```
     serial->flags & ASYNC_SPD_MASK == ASYNC_SPD_[HI, VHI, SHI, WARP]
     // this is an assertion, i.e. what your code must achieve, not how
     ```

     This sets alternate speed to HI: 57600, VHI: 115200, SHI: 230400, WARP: 460800
3. You can set an arbitrary speed using alt_speed as follows:

   - Set `tty->termios->c_cflag` speed to `B38400`. This is unrelated to the speed you chose!
   - Set the intended speed in `tty->alt_speed`. It gets ignored when `alt_speed==0`.
4. You can also an arbitrary speed rate by setting custom divisor as follows:

   - Set `tty->termios->c_cflag` speed to `B38400`. This is unrelated to the speed you chose!

     ```
     bool set_baudrate(int fd, long baudrate) {
       struct termios term;
       if (tcgetattr(fd, &term)) return false;
       term.c_cflag &= ~(CBAUD | CBAUDEX);
       term.c_cflag |= B38400;
       if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &term)) return false;
       // cont'd below
     ```
   - Call `TIOCSSERIAL` ioctl with `struct serial_struct` set as follows:

     ```
     serial->flags & ASYNC_SPD_MASK == ASYNC_SPD_CUST
     serial->custom_divisor == serial->baud_base / your_new_baudrate
     // these are assertions, i.e. what your code must achieve, not how
     ```

   How to do it? First get the structure filled (including `baud_base` you need) by calling `TIOCGSERIAL` ioctl. Then modify it to indicate the new baudrate and set it with `TIOCSSERIAL`:

   ```
         // cont'd
         struct serial_struct serial;
         if (ioctl(fd, TIOCGSERIAL, &serial)) return false;
         serial->flags &= ~ASYNC_SPD_MASK;
         serial->flags |= ASYNC_SPD_CUST;
         serial->custom_divisor = serial->baud_base / baudrate.
         if (ioctl(fd, TIOCSSERIAL, &serial)) return false;
         return true;
      }
   ```

Comment: Everything I am finding is about going to HIGHER baud rates, which is helpful, but I need to support some antique devices with extremely LOW baud rates (something like 50).  Does this answer also apply in that direction as well?

Comment: It doesn't matter which way it goes, it's a generic answer about setting non-standard baud rates. The hardware may not support very low baudrates, but it's worth trying. For example, the FTDI driver should accept the baudrate of 50, but I don't recall how wide is the divider counter in their chips. For 50 baud output, the simplest thing to do is to get any Arduino, and bit-bang you teletype. It may be cool to add a Baudot line discipline to Linux, if it doesn't exist (it'd translate between ASCII and Baudot). There should be no problem getting the 45.5 baudrate. Look up Curious Marc's vids :)

Comment: Thanks!  Since you're listening... Would we use symbols like B576000 the same way as explained above or do those require something else?  Also, are there any special notes about using the BOTHER speed?  (I found the setting in https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/asm-generic/termbits.h)

Comment: Where did B57600 even come from? I haven't mentioned that symbol. Please help me understand what is hard to follow in the answer - I wish to improve it. It's meant to be clear. You have three choices. #2 doesn't apply, since you want none of the four baudrates listed. You are left with choosing between #3 and #4. Then you follow it to the letter. Per #3 you'd set the intended speed in `tty->alt_speed`. Per #4 you'd set the divider as shown, i.e. `your_new_baudrate` would be replaced with `50`. Help please.

Comment: The symbol I referenced is found in the linux header I linked.  Since your answer didn't mention the use of the BOTHER symbol or any of the baud rates that follow it in the header, I guess I was wondering if there might be a 5th method for setting up a port with those.  Sorry for any confusion I generated -- this is just curiosity rather than something I need to resolve at this time.

Comment: You'd only need some other method if the ones shown here didn't work. Specifically, I know that the last two work with the Linux FTDI driver, since I had my dirty fingers in that code :)

Comment: I will probably need to configure a port with asymmetric baud rates (for example TX 50, RX 1200) in order to replace one component in a 40 year old system.  The method for that is probably the same as using BOTHER, which (I think) requires use of TERMIOS2 struct and associated settings.